# "for loop" and $() combination limitation

Tags: bash, shell

ok, i'm working on a different kinda of script but the problem comes down to something like this: assume the following "for loop":

```
for i in $(ls -l); do echo $i; done
```

the problem is that "for loop" separate values by space, so each "i" equals to each word separated by space in 'ls -l'. Hence the output is something like this:

> > total
> >
> > 24
> >
> > drwxrwxr-x.
> >
> > 2
> >
> > james
> >
> > james
> >
> > 4096
> >
> > Oct
> >
> > 26
> >
> > 16:56
> >
> > bg
> >
> > .
> >     .
> >     .

but I want throughout each irritation variable **"i" be equal to ENTIRE line** of 'ls -a' instead of each word. In other word "i" be equal to entire line

```
"drwxrwxr-x.  2 james james 4096 Oct 26 16:56 bg"
```

instead of irritating through each word. I've tried many workarounds, none of them has worked and kinda freaks me out.

Is there a way to tell "for loop" to separate by **new line** instead of space

P.S. The above example is just for illustration (you might argue that it's a bit pointless) but my problem is something similar to that.

Comment: Generally, parsing the output of the `ls` command is a bad idea.  Using [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) means that you want all the output mangled into separate words.  As indicated in the answer(s), use `read line`, or `read perms  links owner group size date1 date2 date3 name` or thereabouts. Or you play games with `$IFS`, but parsing `ls` output is still messy and unreliable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, *IF* the goal is to obtain information from the `ls -l`, then of course you're right. If, on the other hand, `ls -l` is used as an example and the goal is to read input line by line…

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker: That's why I made a comment, not an answer, and why you have an up-vote.  Incidentally, you should probably use `read -r l` in your answer to avoid `read` expanding backslashes, etc.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, agreed (edited).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, As Michael pointed out, the above "ls -l" example is just for illustration. The actual code I'm trying to write is quite different and has nothing to do with "ls -l". I just used it to convey  the idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead you can

```
ls -l | while IFS= read -r l ; do echo "This is it: $l" ; done
```

or do

```
IFS=\\n
```

before running your `for`, but I'd avoid that due to possible side effects.

Comment: the first solution doesn't work (returns just a bunch of "This is it:" lines; what is $l? second solution somehow works but trim line on first occurrence of the letter "n" in the line. double \\ doesn't work

Comment: this would work for now: IFS='PRESS ENTER'  , lets see if I can apply it to my situation

Comment: @James, sorry I read into `line` variable, but echo `$l`. I fixed the `read` line, should work now. Try the first solution again, I'd say it's preferred.

Comment: now it works, but I have to see whether it would work in my main script or not. In the mean time, regarding the IFS, Isn't there some better solution instead of just using IFS='ENTER'?

Comment: With `IFS` one has to be careful, because it's used for all kinds of shell parsing…

Comment: You should always use `read -r` unless you have a good reason not to. **Edit:** You added that just as I finished typing this comment. Seems legit.

Comment: Agreed, @nyuszika7h. The truth is — I remembered that, but didn't remember what exactly the option is ;-)